# EaselJS - Is it possible to add a BlurFilter to a line?

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I'm attempting to add a blur effect to a single line using easelJS. I've been following the BlurFilter demo in the createJS docs (except that they are using a circle instead of a line). My shape disappears completely unless I remove the shape.cache call. Is this possible with a line or is blur limited to shapes?

```
function drawShape() {
  var shape = new createjs.Shape();
  shape.graphics.setStrokeStyle(10, "round")
  .beginStroke(colorPalette.shape[0])
  .beginFill(colorPalette.shape[0])
  .moveTo(200,400)
  .lineTo(1500,400);
  shape.cursor = "pointer";

  var blurFilter = new createjs.BlurFilter(50, 50, 1);
  shape.filters = [blurFilter];
  var bounds = blurFilter.getBounds();
  shape.cache(-50+bounds.x, -50+bounds.y, 100+bounds.width, 100+bounds.height); // Code works if I remove this line

  updateStage(shape); // Utility function that calls addChild and update on stage
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()" onresize="resize()">
        <!-- App -->
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that [shapes have no bounds](http://blog.createjs.com/update-width-height-in-easeljs/), and you are just adding the blur bounds onto the generated blur bounds. If you inspect the `bounds` in your fiddle, you will see that it is just returning the blur amount in either direction:

```
// blurFilter.getBounds()
Rectangle {x: -51, y: -51, width: 102, height: 102}
```

If you add these values to 50 and 100 in your `cache` call, it will still provide you bounds that do not include the graphics you have created. Something more accurate would be:

```
// Add in the offset position of the graphics and the coords of the shape
shape.cache(200 - 5 + bounds.x, 400 - 5 + bounds.y, 1300 + 10 + bounds.width, 10 + bounds.height);
```

Note that the `-5` and `+10` account for the width of the line.

Here is an updated fiddle where I have set the "bounds" on the shape itself, and then add those bounds into the cache call: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/cevymo3w/1/

Hope that provides some insight.

Comment: Thank you! Was banging my head against this for hours, this explains it.